# StructureMap: Unable to produce unique instance for open-generic factory in nested container

Tags: .net, structuremap

I had been successfully using open-generics in SM using code such as

```
For(typeof(IConnectedClient<,>)).Use(typeof(WcfConnectedClient<,>));
```

I then needed to start using nested containers for a "session" scope within my application. **Every `IConnectedClient` created within this nested container I need to be unique and also automatically disposed.**

Unfortunately, after much experimentation, I can't get both of these requirements satisfied.

All these fail to actually return unique instances, but the instance is disposed:

```
For(typeof(IConnectedClient<,>)).Use(typeof(WcfConnectedClient<>)).AlwaysUnique(); 
For(typeof(IConnectedClient<,>)).Use(typeof(WcfConnectedClient<,>)).SetLifecycleTo<TransientLifecycle>();
For(typeof(IConnectedClient<,>)).LifecycleIs(new TransientLifecycle()).Use(typeof(WcfConnectedClient<,>));
For(typeof(IConnectedClient<,>)).LifecycleIs(new TransientLifecycle()).Use(typeof(WcfConnectedClient<,>)).LifecycleIs<TransientLifecycle>();
```

This returns unique instances but they are not disposed (and I expect perRequest is not what I want):

```
  For(typeof(IConnectedClient<,>)).LifecycleIs(new UniquePerRequestLifecycle()).Use(typeof(WcfConnectedClient<,>));
```

How do I configure the open-generic to work that both creates new instances and disposes them for a nested container?

Answer (score 0):

I've upgraded to SM 4.5.x and the following now works:

```
For(typeof(IConnectedClient<,>)).LifecycleIs(new UniquePerRequestLifecycle()).Use(typeof(WcfConnectedClient<,>));
```

So it seems maybe this was a bug in 3.1.4 version.